# Sketch skipping the OPEN Arduino inputs

Tags: arduino-mega

Folks,
I am a beginner to Arduino. I have a sketch that tests a set of INPUTS for HIGH or LOW by using a 'for' loop. When the for loop reaches an INPUT which is kept OPEN (no wires connected to it), the for loop apparently 'skips' that INPUT and move on to the next. However, if I have +5V connected to any INPUTS within the range of the for loop, it works correctly. Any thoughts what's is happening here?

Comment: probably bad programming ... the arduino will do exactly what you tell it to do, so you are giving it incorrect instructions

Comment: You can edit your code into the question if you want to try for a more a specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should always connect something to an input to pull it high or low when no signal is present.  The simplest thing is to activate the built-in pullup resistor, which will result in the input returning HIGH when there is nothing connected.  If that's not compatible with your particular use, add a resistor from the input to ground (10k-100k is fine) so that it will return LOW when nothing else is connected.  If the input is just floating, it is susceptible to noise causing random state changes. The input impedance is very high (100 Meg) so it can pick up static and other mischief.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll avoid floating inputs.